# Drupal 7 standard registration form wrong fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, registration

I'm not a drupal/web programmer but have a site on drupal and after I reloaded server, user registration standard form has some failures.

It changed names of the fields while they work fine.

Instead of "Login" label now I have "Search" label but again users can still login. But this label makes me crazy and it is quite hard to understand where I can find this problem to fix it.

How I can change this label to be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this code to your theme/template.php and rename my_theme_form_alter to your theme name

```
    function my_theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
      switch($form_id){
     case 'user_register_form':
        unset($form['account']['mail']['#title']);
        $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = '';
        $form['account']['mail']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('E-mail');
        $form['account']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-elements';

        $form['account']['pass']['#description'] = '';
        $form['account']['pass']['#process'] = array('form_process_password_confirm', 'register_alter_password_confirm');
        $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Register');

        break;
  }
}
function register_alter_password_confirm($element) {

  $element['pass1']['#title_display'] = "invisible";
  $element['pass1']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t("Password");
  $element['pass2']['#title_display'] = "invisible";
  $element['pass2']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t("Confirm password");
  return $element;
}
```